# Automatically Adjust Font Metrics to Match a Different Font Using `fonttools`

Tags: python, fonts, typography, ttx-fonttools

I have two fonts:

- **font A:** open-source font
- **font B:** proprietary font whose metrics I'm trying to match.

How do I create a replacement font (**font C**) with the glyphs from **font A** but with the metrics from font B?

Also, I want all characters not present in **font B** not to be present in **font C** and I want to receive a warning for every character present in **font B** but not in **font A**, so that I can create a replacement that supports the exact same characters.

I think that `fonttools` would be a good tool for this, but I am not very familiar with the way it works.